# How can I use spacebar to close Matplotlib/Pyplot plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In [Close a matplotlib figure using keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54635335/7758804) I learned that you can add keybinds to various matplotlib commands, including key.quit which exits the plot.

The keybinds can be assigned via:
`plt.rcParams["keymap.quit"] = ['ctrl+w', 'cmd+w', 'q']`

However, when I add `space` or `spacebar` to the list, space doesn't work. I know that list is defaults, so either I'm not modifying them at all or I have the name for spacebar wrong.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a paucity of documentation on exactly what the key mappings are for this functionality, but you can find out with this code snippet:

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> fig = plt.figure()
>>> fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', lambda evt: print(repr(evt.key)))
8
```

Then

```
>>> plt.show()
```

will open an empty plot window.  Pressing keys in the window will print to your terminal the associated keymap code.

When pressing the space bar I get:

```
' '
```

Confirmed that setting `plt.rcParams['keymap.quit'].append(' ')` works--pressing the space bar closes the window.